# Turn off NavBar icon on one page only

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I want to turn off my menu icon when in the menu page context (normal page not modal), but have it turned on for any other page. I'm using Meteor, React and React-Router. The below image shows the basic structure.

I'm currently changing the title text within `.header-center>span` using a ReactiveVar but it changes per page, so it seems reasonable there.

I'm wanting an elegant way to switch-off/hide the the content of `.header-left>img` for one page only and revert when navigating away. Not sure if I should be doing it in CSS or JS. Any ideas appreciated.

[image: page html]

Comment: OK, how do you get down voted for asking a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.props.location.pathname` to know when to turn it off and on. like this.

```
<div className="header-left">
    {this.props.location.pathname === 'home' ? <img className="sidebar-icon" /> : null}
</div>
```

This code will only show the icon on the `/home` page, so you'll have to update it to behave like you want it to.
But depending on how many checks and pages you want to use you might get better of with a maintainable function/method here.

Answer (score 0):

Add some class to your menu, for example `class="menu menu-hidden-icon ..etc.."`, and you will be able to hide your icon with this:

```
.menu-hidden-icon .sidebar-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the path URL and apply `hide()` JQuery function.

```
var pathUrl = window.location.pathname;
if(pathUrl == '/menu'){
  $(".header-left").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these work, but I went with @Lucas Reppe Welander's answer because it allowed the icon to restore on navigating away. Many thanks to all. All I did was flip the logic like this:

```
{this.props.router.location.pathname === "/grid" 
   ? null 
   : <img className="menu-icon" onClick={()=> this.onMenu()} src={"../icons/hamburger.svg"} /> }
```